# Bootstrap 5 variable card width

Tags: width, bootstrap-5, card

I am using bootstrap 5 and have a card on a page, it is the only thing on the page.

I am fairly new to bootstrap, long time programmer.

On a phone the width of the card is great, on a monitor its width is way too wide.  What is the best way for the card to be 100% vw on xs, sm devices but a smaller width on larger screens?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div  class="row justify-content-xs-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking out bootstrap grid system to work with the screen sizes. In your code the  `<div class="col">` means the col is automatic instead of any specified width. You can use  `<div class="col-md-6">`, here `md` means from medium to higher the `col` with is going to be `6`. That achieves your expected output. Also in `<div  class="row justify-content-xs-center">` xs is not required because, `xs` simply says the content should be centered only in `xs`, instead you can simply use `justify-content-center`

Now the code should look something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div  class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            Text here
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you should use media query.if there is little more code it would be helpful to check.